# Filling a list with regular expression results python

Tags: python, regex, list, pattern-matching

I would like to search a string for specific substrings and store these substrings in a list using re, how would I go about doing that?

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import stdin
import re as reg

regex = reg.compile(r"\".*\"")#match "  match me  "
line = stdin.readline().strip().split()
myList = [ match for match in regex.finditer(line) ]
print myList
```

Here is example input:

```
"RUn.exe O" "" "   2ne, " two! . " "
```

This expected output, No need to add the brackets, that was just me clarifying the specific matches needed:

```
<RUn.exe O>
<>
<   2ne, >
<two!>
<.>
< >
```

So basically, anything between quotes is part of the output and should be written to the list and anything without quotes should just be written to the list

Thanks guys

P.S. where can I learn about using regex in python? I am comfortable using regex with grep or awk, but I am still new to python and I especially like the idea of compiling a regex to be used over and over, but I don't know where to learn more about that

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you add examples of input data and desired output?

Comment: Srry bout that, I was very tired after posting this so I didn't have time to add examples before I hit the hay. I have now added example input/output. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, you might be able to do without the for-loop though...

```
line = '"RUn.exe O" "" "   2ne, " two! . " "'
import re
regex = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"|[^\s]+')
matches = [el.strip('"') for el in regex.findall(line)]

print '\n'.join(matches)
```

You can use both ' and " to make a string in python. As I make the string using ', the string doesn't end when encountering a ", and I don't have to escape it. If you're making a string that contains either ' or ", it's convenient to use the other one as a start/stop.

The regex works as follows: first find a ". [^"] means anything that is not (^) a ", and match any number of this (*). Then find another ".
Similarly the [^\s] means anything that is not a whitespace, and the + means one or more.

There might be a clue in re's documentation: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: Srry I wasn't very clear before, I have clarified some details now. The regex I had created does not always match what I need that is why the one you have posted will not work either. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Can you please explain what that regex does? How does it match quotes without you having to escape them ('\')? And can you explain why the first bracket [^"] is not matched literally although it is proceeded by a quote. Isn't "\s" only matching whitespace characters? And what is the * matching? Your solution worked very well, but I don't know how or why it works.